# Extracting data from an Activerecord with joined tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
Project.joins(:project_status).where(id: 1).first
```

I want to use a string such as "Project.ProjectStatus.name" and it will return the name of the joined project status, and simply something like Project.name.

.read_attribute() doesn't seem to go deeper to joined/included records. .send works when I do .send('ProjectStatus').send('id') but this does not seem ideal and could be dangerous, these variables come from users.

It's for a templating engine so I might have something like..
"{{Project.name}} status was changed to {{ProjectStatus.name}}"

Are there any gems I can pick up? I'm really exhausting what I've been searching for in Google now. In CakePHP I have used Hash::extract before which is a little like xpath.

Comment: `Project.joins(:project_status).where(id: 1).select('project_statuses.name as project_status_name, projects.*')`

Answer (score 0):

What is the association between Project and ProjectStatus here? I assume it's `has_one: :project_status`?

Anyway, if you want to be able to call `@project.name` ( where `@project` is an instance of the class `Project`; `.name` should be specific to each individual project, so you should define it as an instance method rather than the class method `Project.name`), you can create a method in Project model:

```
def name
  project_status.name
end
```

Assuming that you previously defined the association in model as

```
has_one: :project_status
```

Now the name can be retrieved simply by using `.name`